# Proof that a real number is adherent value of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence. Prove that, in order for the real number $a$ to be the adherent value of $(x_n)$, it is necessary and sufficient that, for all $\epsilon>0$ and all $k$, with $k$ being a natural number, there exists $n>k$ such that $|x_n - a|<\epsilon$.

Attempt: For the sufficient condition, take $\epsilon$ equal to $1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},\dots$ and get $n_1<n_2<n_3<\dots<n_k$ with $|x_{n_k} - a|<\frac{1}{k}$.

What would be a necessary condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the adherent value of our sequence. Then it is the limit of some subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ (definition of adherence value) and then, from the definition of limit of a sequence, there exists a subsequence such that, for all $\epsilon>0$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists \space n>k; \space |x_n - a|<\epsilon$. This proves the necessary condition.